# Cordova 2.6 / 2.7 iOS app timing out

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an app that I've been running successfully for the best part of a year built with Cordova 2.1.  Recently I decided to start a new build with 2.6 and it runs fine on iOS 5, but not iOS 6.  Went through the crash logs which all point to "[app] failed to launch in time". Unhelpfully it also has 'backtrace not available'.

To try to pin down what I'm doing wrong, I basically started from scratch - create a default Cordova app.  However when I run that - just the very basic app that is created when you create a new project from the command line - it also has the same error.  Get the splash screen, stalls and then crashes with the failed to launch in time error.

The apps run fine in the simulator, but when I run them on a device from Xcode or archive them and install them, nothin'.

Im using Cordova 2.7.0, Xcode 4.6.2 on OSX 10.7.5.  If it helps, one of the full crash logs is below...

---

Incident Identifier: EDD1A74C-953F-4D66-9199-2D87E3AD9D3F
CrashReporter Key:   e72939db0dce8f4abf935c5b5c7e2aa4a2a4b880
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         test01 [10376]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/3AEE3B27-11B9-48FA-9190
A7A53BF78E48/test01.app/test01
Identifier:      test01
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-05-01 11:00:55.046 +1000
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
[app] failed to launch in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 20.000 (user 20.000, system 0.000), 100% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
0x2fe70000 - 0x2fe90fff  dyld armv7  <280610df5ed43ec7aa00629a27009302> /usr/lib/dyld

---

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever happen to find a resolution to this?